# High-side driver current monitoring via microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, current-sensing, high-side

I'm building an automotive power distribution module which makes use of the Infineon [BTS50010](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTS50010-1LUA-DataSheet-v01_10-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c85ecb3470186015e6ce406a0) high-side driver.

The high-side driver current is monitored via the sense pin (IS) connected to a microcontroller, see below schematic:

[image: BTS50010 Application Schematic]

If we say R<sub>Load</sub> is a switching a load such as an ignition coil and as such, results in a varying HSD sense pin output, what would be a good way of accurately measuring load current?

The only way I can think of doing this would be by oversampling the current sense output with averaging in an attempt to calculate an accurate current value.

Comment: See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272177/high-side-regulation-of-current-for-proportional-valve) for a very similar circuit. Basically just put a current sense resistor in series with the high side driver and measure across it in some convenient way.

Comment: @Lundin, I'm not sure how that would result in a different measurement than sampling the IS pin on the HSD?

Comment: The main advantage is that you don't have to "marry" Infineon, so that you can replace the driver IC with something else. Infineon has a tradition of major logistics meltdowns every 5-10 years or so, when it becomes impossible to buy their products during an extended period of 1-2 years. Good products, horrible logistics - the company can't be trusted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The capacitor `CSENSE` in the schematic you posted acts as an analog averaging filter (RC low-pass). If you want to average the signal more, you can increase the value of this cap. No oversampling is needed.

Comment: Thanks. Was overthinking this a bit.

Comment: @Joe Overthinking is half of an engineer's job description. :)